# How to check which value is passing in ternary operator method in Junit?

Tags: java, junit

I am new to Junit and trying to write test case for the following scenario.

```
public List<String> transformColumns(String action){
        return action.equals("delete"))?
                tableInsert("onetwo", false)
                :tableInsert("onetwothree", true);
    }
```

If, I pass **action** value as **transformColumns("delete")**, **tableInsert("onetwo", false)** method should be called with value of **false** in second parameter.  How to validate the parameter value of called method in Junit?

Comment: Why don’t you check the return value from the transformColumns method and leave it at that ? Otherwise you’re making a test that knows too much about the implementation details. If the method has side effects verify those happen as expected too.

Comment: Do you want to use a mocking library like "mockito"? It has verify methods to check if a method is called as expected.

Comment: You could use Mockito ArgumentCaptor. [ArgumentCaptor](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) How to use: (https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor)

Comment: @NathanHughes I am unable to check based on return value, because it won't return any data to identify parameter value of called method

Comment: I will try to use Mockita, please provide simple example if possible

Comment: @hardcode Can you check the side effects which will happen when you call `tableInsert()` with `false` or `true`?

Comment: @Progman Not anything unique in both way it returning some random metadata.  I analyzed return value, there is no way to differentiate by return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) to [verify](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify-T-) that some method is called. In this case you can use [`spy()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-T-) on the object you want to test, call the `transformColumns()` method and check with `verify()`, that the `tableInsert()` method was indeed called. The unit test method might look like this:

```
@Test
public void mockitoTest() {
    Foobar mock = Mockito.spy(Foobar.class);

    mock.transformColumns("delete");
            
    Mockito.verify(mock).tableInsert(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(false));
    
}
```

This test will pass, as the call `transformColumns("delete")` will call the `tableInsert()` method internally with the `false` value for the second argument. If you change the argument for `transformColumns()` or change the expected argument `false` to `true` you will see that this unit test method will fail with an error like this (the expression `Mockito.eq(true)` was used to show the error):

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
foobar.tableInsert(<any string>, true);
-> at testing.AllTests.mockitoTest(AllTests.java:14)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
foobar.transformColumns("delete");
-> at testing.AllTests.mockitoTest(AllTests.java:12)
foobar.tableInsert("onetwo", false);
-> at testing.Foobar.transformColumns(Foobar.java:8)
```